# Zend Framework route not working when passing URLs as route parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

When I try to pass a URL in the route below it gives me 404 error. If I replace the URL with any other string it works.

This is the route.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                'user/logout/:preserve/:ref',
                array(
                        'action'     => 'logout',
                        'controller' => 'user',
                        'module'     => 'root',
                        'preserve' => false,
                        'ref' => ''
                )
        );
        $router->addRoute('logout', $route);
```

This is how I am generating URLs in my views.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('preserve' => 1, 'ref' => $this->url()), 'logout'); ?>">Logout</a>
```

This is the URL which is generated by the URL view helper.

```
/user/logout/1/http%3A%2F%2Feop.localhost.com%2F
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by applying the `urlencode()` function to my generated URL.

I hope it saves someone else some time.